# Updating/inserting into a table with Always Encrypted columns using EF Core 5

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, savechanges, always-encrypted

I'm having trouble using Entity Framework Core 5 with the "Always Encrypted" feature in a ASP.NET Core 5 API. I've configured an Azure Key Vault and updated the connection string as necessary. I can read encrypted column data successfully, with code like this:

```
await using var context = new RcContext();
Company c = await context.Companies.FindAsync(id);
```

where the `Companies` table has an encrypted column. The encrypted column is defined in the database as datatype `varchar(16)` and is returned as plain text in a string member of the entity.

However, trying to update a company or insert new companies using `context.SaveChanges()` is failing. I get the error

> SqlException: Operand type clash: nvarchar(4000) encrypted with ... is incompatible with varchar(16) encrypted with ...

Some suggestions for solving this point to using `SqlCommand` from `SqlClient` or stored procedures, or increasing the column's size in the database to `nvarchar(max)`.

Is EF Core not capable of using the normal `SaveChanges()` pattern to make updates to data in a SQL Server with Always Encrypted columns? How do I make this work with EF Core?

Comment: In your entity class is the related field decorated with `[Column(TypeName="varchar(16)")]`? The error message sounds like it's currently decorated with `[MaxLength(4000)]`.

Comment: The entity type is a POCO, with no decorations. The encrypted column is a string. Just for a test, I changed the encrypted column in the database to be type `nvarchar(max)` and `context.SaveChanges()` now works. I don't think I can go with this solution, however.

Answer (score 3):

With Always Encrypted, the SQL Client needs to know the size of the columns so it can do the encryption on the client. So columns must be attributed like:

`[Column(TypeName = "varchar(16)")] public string PaymentCreditCard { get; set; }`

I only had to attribute the encrypted columns, not every column. Our source base had not used data annotations prior to this effort, and it wasn't clear to me that they are *required* for Always Encrypted to work.

Comment: In my case the length of the column was different that one specified on database, but this answer pointed me in right direction. 

Looks like configuration file also works:
builder.Property(x => x.Email).HasMaxLength(250);